# Allow Anyone to Upload Files Directly to my Google Drive

Tags: google-apps-script, file-upload, drag-and-drop

I would like to allow my students to send me one or more files directly to my google drive via a form where they would just enter their name and choose the file(s) to send (drag and drop would be great). A folder with their name would be created in a specific folder on my drive and a warning email would be sent to me. Do you think this is feasible with google script? Thanks in advance.
An example [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=unaDRVKy_uA) but paying ...

Answer (score 0):

I've checked and Google Forms already allows for a File Upload kind of question (with drag and drop too).

It automatically creates a folder in your Google Drive (altough it doesnt create a folder for every student) (example [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8j9XC.png)) and in the spreadsheet that it automatically generates there is a permanent link to that file (example [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cfeAL.png)).

If that's not what you are looking for and you need the 'Folder per student' feature then yes, you can use google apps script to move files in folders quite easily.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Google Forms does allow file uploads but the uploader must have a google account it seems.

Comment: If you want somebody to upload files to your Google drive without having a Google account, your best bet would be to create a [Webapp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) deployed as "you". In this case, any person pasting the WebApp URL into the browser could perform requests like uploading files to your Drive without having to authenticate with his Google account.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers, I found my happiness here thanks to the superb work of Charles Plucker : https://github.com/CharlesPlucker/drive-multi-upload/